# Redirecting Heroku NodeJS app to https

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, https

I have a Heroku app with Automated Certificate Management. I already checked how to redirect to https with req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] but I'm getting 'https' in that field instead of 'http' and my app is not redirecting to https. I have DNS in DNS Made Easy. What should I do to make a redirection from root domain and subdomain to https in web browser?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Redirect http to https
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https'){
    res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

This will redirect all the requests coming from http to https